# How many time does a SHA-1 computation require on modern CPU/GPU?

Tags: brute-force-attack, sha-1, birthday-attack

I am considering how long a SHA-1 computation will need on modern CPU/GPU's. Just in case we are interested in brute forcing and consider the birthday paradoxon, then we need consider the SHA-1 output range of 160 (?) Bits.

The number of brute force attempts, until our attack is by 50% successful, requires $\left\lceil 1.18\cdot \sqrt{2^{160}} \right\rceil \sim 1.43 \cdot 10^{24}$ attemptions. How long would, say Intel's i3/5/7, require until this computations and comparisons are done?

The measure should be given in time per mega byte.

Comment: So where are you stuck in calculations?

Comment: You know that this has been done, by an attack about ten thousand times cheaper than brute force?  https://shattered.it/  (Now, of course, you can extend that collision by any suffix you want at essentially zero cost to get arbitrarily many other collisions.)

Comment: ...Also, how do you measure the answer to your question per megabyte?

Comment: @fgrieu Actually, cpb performance should be somewhat consistent across generations, because AFAIK only low-power server- / NAS-targeted CPUs (like Pentiums and Celerons) got SHA-EX. I'd guess Intel considered SHA not to be a concern on the Core i series and used the chip area in a better way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not enough research was done; even the assertion that the _"birthday paradoxon"_ (sic) applies seems uncertain and hard to reconcile with a result _"in time per mega byte"_, or at least unjustified. Reposted with fix of the error pointed out in [SEJPM's comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/51605/555#comment113999_51605).

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I know that attack but I would like to know, how long such a brute force will take while the inputsize increases (in mb). So brute force at X mb input will take Y seconds, or different: Y/X seconds per mb (input).

I cannot measure that on my own, since I don't know know how many cycles a SHA-1 opertion perfomes on X mb of data input, and I also do not know how many cycles can be done on actual GPU's or CPU's.

Comment: @Shalec: Still not clear on what you mean by input.  Do you mean a chosen prefix?  Once you have chosen a prefix, you can partially precompute SHA-1 on that chosen prefix to get a replacement initialization vector.  Then you make a collision on however many blocks your attack requires, using that replacement initialization vector, at the same speed as any other chosen prefix, including an empty one.

Comment: I just thought about selecting a file and doing a hash-sum of its content. So the size of this file will vary, but the output-size is constant. Therefore I thought about measuring this in s/mb (required seconds to hash 1mb of input) But since I saw the list, that SHA-1 vary on input size, this won't fit at all. But, this could be an approximation in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SHA-1 runs at 2.24 cpb on an AMD Ryzen 1700 (at 2994MHz) for somewhat short messages (ie 576 bytes)](https://bench.cr.yp.to/results-hash.html) which is a very relevant number given that you don't want to hash large messages, but *many* messages.

So for the full message you need a little less than 1300 cycles. So now suppose we have an optimized architecture / shorter messages and get this down to 1000 cycles per attempt.

You can now compute the speed yourself. In this case a Ryzen achieves $$8\cdot 2994\cdot 10^6/10^3\approx 24\cdot 10^6$$ attempts per second, that is, 24 million.

Comment: If I validate that for a 4096 bit input message, I reach rounded $4\cdot 10^9$ years per birthday-attack. Is that right or did I did any mistake? The Ryzen-speed is $$R := 8\cdot 2994\cdot 10^6 c/s$$ (cycles per second) which leads to the measure $$A := R/(2\cdot 10^3)\ \left[ (c/s)(c/a)\right]= 4\cdot 2994\cdot 10^3 [a/s]\sim 12\cdot 10^6 [a/s]$$ (attemps per second) and this leads to the required time for brute forcing: $$T := 1.43\cdot 10^{24} / A\  \left[a/(a/s)\right] = 1.2 \cdot 10^{17} s \sim 4 \cdot 10^9\ years$$

Comment: If I'll do a parallelization of n Ryzen cards, it is $R\gets R^n$ through that computation?

Comment: Oh.. I meant $R\gets n\cdot R$.

Comment: @Shalec yes, using $n$ Ryzen CPUs in parallel should roughly linearly reduce the required time.